# MySQL Duplicate Primary Key Error On Update

Tags: mysql, sql-update

For some reason whenever I try to update a record in my table I get a "Duplicate entry '5687' for key 'PRIMARY'" error.  My query is:

```
UPDATE 
    `patients` 
SET
    first_name=AES_ENCRYPT('Floyd','mykey'),
    last_name=AES_ENCRYPT('Resler','mykey'),
    birthdate='1899-01-01 00:00:00',
    sex='M',
    account=AES_ENCRYPT('123-456-789','mykey'),
    user_id='0',
    hospital_id='2' 
WHERE 
    patient_id='5687'
```

This happens on any update to this table.  I've been doing MySQL for a long time and have never seen this happen on an UPDATE.  BTW, I'm not really using "mykey" as an encryption key!

EDIT
Here is my CREATE TABLE output:

```
CREATE TABLE `patients` (
  `patient_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `last_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `birthdate` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `sex` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `date_stamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `account` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `deleted` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `hospital_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `deleted_by_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `deleted_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `no_piccs` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `deceased` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `converted` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`patient_id`),
  KEY `fname` (`first_name`),
  KEY `lname` (`last_name`),
  KEY `deleted` (`deleted`),
  KEY `hospital_id` (`hospital_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5938 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
```

I did double-check to make sure there are no duplicate patient_ids.

Comment: Please share your `SHOW CREATE TABLE` statement results also. Edit your question to add these details as well!

Comment: If this stores data on actual people this "encryption" solution is in no way adequate. You should hire a consultant that can better advise how to do this, plus ensure you're properly compliant (e.g. HIPAA certified) before proceeding.

Comment: any chance you somehow violated this constraint already (i.e. by disabling integrity checks for an import or something like that) and now the database is tripping up? Check if you can find multiple entries with the same key

Comment: tadman - thanks for the advice.  The site does reside on a HIPAA compliant server.

Comment: Is there any chance you have a trigger associated with this table.

Comment: I can't believe I missed the fact that I had added a trigger and didn't take out the key field in my log table!  I feel silly!  Thanks for figuring it out for me!